# Supply a default value for an incomplete SQL join

Tags: sql

Sorry I don't know if there's proper name for 'incomplete join' but consider this sort of query, designed to return details of every sale:

```
SELECT a.id, a.productId, b.productDescription FROM Sales a, AdditionalProductData b WHERE a.productId = b.productId;
```

In a situation where `AdditionalProductData` doesn't guarantee to to have a row for every `productId`, but I want to return a result for every row in `Sales`, how can I modify my query to return either `null` or some default value e.g. "unknown" in such cases? I want to ensure sales of unregistered products are not omitted.

(It is a slightly contrived example, and indicates a problem in the DB, but those are outside scope of the question)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and **easier to convert to outer join** if needed!

Comment: Please show sample data, desired results, and add an appropriate database tag -- something that someone with your reputation should know.  Also explain why `sales` would have references to non-existent products.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, I think must've learned SQL when `JOIN` was less well supported perhaps and I only end up writing SQL sporadically. I shall bear it in mind, for me JOIN syntax is less intuitive but if that's the norm I'll make the effort :)

Comment: I'm even older, and today I only regret it took me so long before I switched to explicit JOIN's.

Comment: @jarlh the dangers of letting coders near the database eh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OUTER JOIN` :

```
SELECT a.productId, b.productName
FROM Products b LEFT JOIN
     Sales a
     ON a.productId = b.id;
```

> but I want to return a result for every row in Sales

Do the table swapping :

```
SELECT a.productId, COALESCE(b.productName, 'unknown') AS productName
FROM  Sales a LEFT JOIN
      Products b
      ON a.productId = b.id;
```

Comment: This is a nice clear answer however having two options - for what I've asked Vs what you think I should've asked - makes it a bit confusing. I agree having both is useful - I think outer joins are easy to get wrong - but you might add some (brief) explanation the difference for an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You want a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.productName
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON s.productId = p.id;
```

I am guessing you really want at least one row per product.  It doesn't make sense that you would have sales for non-existent products -- at least in most databases.

The above doesn't make sense -- only selecting from one table.  You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.productName, SUM(s.amount)
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     Sales s
     ON s.productId = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.productName;
```

EDIT:

If you really do want one row per `sales`, then you still want a `LEFT JOIN` just in the other order:

```
SELECT s.*, p.productName
FROM Sales s LEFT JOIN
     Products p L
     ON s.productId = p.id;
```

Comment: No, I want one row per sale... even if my product catalogue is incomplete (I know this is bad but it's only an example and you _do_ see such things)

Comment: @Mr.Boy . . . Your question is really incomplete in that case.   You are showing data that doesn't have a correct relationship between the tables and that should be explained.

Comment: I don't know I agree such a defined question needs context (kind of outside the scope) but I've modified the question and added detail to a scenario where it is less weird - we might consider the 2nd table one that provides ancillary data. It _is_ a contrived example though and LEFT/OUTER join is the answer. Been so long since I used them I'd forgotten that's what they did!

Comment: BTW main reason I didn't add sample data was I couldn't recall how to add a table!